# C: 'else' being executed when if condition is satisfied - structures

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, structure

I'm currently learning C from a book, and a question was to write a program to find the time elapsed between 2 times input by the user, which I've done so using a 24 hour format.

The problem is the while loop in the main function does not execute when it should. Which is when the user has entered a time that is out of boundaries (under 0, over 24 hours etc.)

```
while(error == 1) {
    printf("Enter time 1 in the format hours:mins:sec\n");
    scanf("%i:%i:%i", &time1.hours, &time1.minutes, &time1.seconds);
```

The while loop should then keep executing until the user enters a valid time, but instead it just gets skipped.

I think the reason might be because the function that checks the time and assigns the global variable 'error' to equal 1 or 0 is always executing the else statement (which sets error = 0),even when the if statements are true.

```
void checkTime (struct time a)
{   

if(a.hours < 0 || a.hours > 23) {
    printf("Please enter a valid figure for hours in the range 1 to 23\n");
    error = 1;
}

if(a.minutes < 0 || a.minutes > 59) {
    printf("Please enter a valid figure for minutes in the range of 1 to 59\n");
    error = 1;
}

if(a.seconds < 0 || a.seconds > 59) {
    printf("Please enter a valid figure for seconds in the range of 1 to 59\n");
    error = 1;

}

else {
    error = 0;
}
}
```

Is this a logic problem that has something to do with the way structures work?

here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Program to find the time elapsed between 2 times entered by user

int error = 0;

struct time 
{
int hours;
int minutes;
int seconds;
};

//Function to find elapsed time between the 2 arguments
struct time elapsed_time (struct time time1, struct time time2)
{

struct time eTime;


if (time2.hours > time1.hours)
    eTime.hours = time2.hours - time1.hours;
else
    eTime.hours = (24 - time1.hours) + time2.hours;


if (time2.minutes > time1.minutes)
    eTime.minutes = time2.minutes - time1.minutes;
else
    eTime.minutes = (60 - time1.minutes) + time2.minutes;


if (time2.seconds > time1.seconds)
    eTime.seconds = time2.seconds - time1.seconds;
else
    eTime.seconds = (60 - time1.seconds) + time2.seconds;


return eTime;
}

//Function to check if inputed times are within valid parameters
void checkTime (struct time a)
{   

if(a.hours < 0 || a.hours > 23) {
    printf("Please enter a valid figure for hours in the range 1 to 23\n");
    error = 1;
}

if(a.minutes < 0 || a.minutes > 59) {
    printf("Please enter a valid figure for minutes in the range of 1 to 59\n");
    error = 1;
}

if(a.seconds < 0 || a.seconds > 59) {
    printf("Please enter a valid figure for seconds in the range of 1 to 59\n");
    error = 1;

}

else {
    error = 0;
}

}


int main (void)
{   
struct time time1;
struct time time2;
struct time main_eTime;

printf("Enter time 1 in the format hours:mins:sec\n");
scanf("%i:%i:%i", &time1.hours, &time1.minutes, &time1.seconds);

checkTime(time1);

while(error == 1) {
    printf("Enter time 1 in the format hours:mins:sec\n");
    scanf("%i:%i:%i", &time1.hours, &time1.minutes, &time1.seconds);
}

printf("Enter time 2 in the format hours:mins:sec\n");
scanf("%i:%i:%i", &time2.hours, &time2.minutes, &time2.seconds);

checkTime(time2);

while(error == 1) {
    printf("Enter time 2 in the format hours:mins:sec\n");
    scanf("%i:%i:%i", &time2.hours, &time2.minutes, &time2.seconds);
}

main_eTime = elapsed_time(time1, time2);

printf("Elapsed time between time 1 and time 2 is %i:%i:%i\n", main_eTime.hours, 
        main_eTime.minutes, main_eTime.seconds);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Another large problem not mentioned yet is that if `error` does in fact get set to 1, you enter an infinite loop. The `checkTime` should be inside the loop. Aldo you probably want to use `%d` instead of `%i` in scanf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure of your code is:

```
if (COND_1) {
    ...
}

if (COND_2) {
    ...
}

if (COND_3) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

You seem to think that the `else` should run if none of `COND_1`, `COND_2`, or `COND_3` are true. But that's not how it works: `else` attaches to the immediately preceding `if` statement, nothing more. The only part that matters as to whether the `else` block runs is the `COND_3` condition.

What you should do instead is either:

```
if (COND_1) {
    ...
}
else if (COND_2) {
    ...
}
else if (COND_3) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

By structuring the code this way, we make sure exactly one block is executed.

... or:

```
error = 0;

if(a.hours < 0 || a.hours > 23) {
    printf("Please enter a valid figure for hours in the range 1 to 23\n");
    error = 1;
}

if(a.minutes < 0 || a.minutes > 59) {
    printf("Please enter a valid figure for minutes in the range of 1 to 59\n");
    error = 1;
}

if(a.seconds < 0 || a.seconds > 59) {
    printf("Please enter a valid figure for seconds in the range of 1 to 59\n");
    error = 1;
}
```

By setting `error = 0` in the beginning you don't need an `else` block at all.

Comment: I think the latter solution is better as it will report all the possible problems with the input.

Comment: and don't use a global would be a great advice

Answer (score 2):

I think there is something wrong with your branching condition, particularly in the `checkTime` function. The `else` condition at the last will execute if the seconds are valid, and it does not care whether you input the hour and minutes correctly or not.

Change it to:

```
void checkTime (struct time a)
{   
    if(a.hours < 0 || a.hours > 23) {
        printf("Please enter a valid figure for hours in the range 1 to 23\n");
        error = 1;
    }

    else if(a.minutes < 0 || a.minutes > 59) {
        printf("Please enter a valid figure for minutes in the range of 1 to 59\n");
        error = 1;
    }

    else if(a.seconds < 0 || a.seconds > 59) {
        printf("Please enter a valid figure for seconds in the range of 1 to 59\n");
        error = 1;
    }

    else {
        error = 0;
    }
}
```

The above will run the `else` block only if all three variables (hours, minutes and seconds are valid).